# How can i click and just own class can be shown on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="item text-center">
   <div class="class1">  <p> Something </p> </div>
</div>

<div class="item text-center">
   <div class="class1">  <p> Something </p> </div>
</div>


$(".class1").hide();
$(".item").click(function () {
    $(".class1").show();
})
```

I want that when the user click div of item, its own class1 should be show();
But in my codes, when the user click item of div, all class1 shows.

How can i do that just own class can be shown?

Comment: `$(this).find(‘.class1’)` might do it

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you need to use DOM traversal to access the `.class1` element(s) within the clicked `.item`. To do that you can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to access the element which raised the event. Try this:

```js
$(".item").click(function() {
  $(this).find(".class1").show();
})
```

```css
.class1 { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item text-center">
  Foo
  <div class="class1">
    <p> Something </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item text-center">
  Bar
  <div class="class1">
    <p> Something </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note in the example that I used CSS to hide the `.class1` elements instead of JS. This is because JS runs *after* the DOM has loaded, so can result in elements being visible for a short time before they are hidden. CSS runs before this, so avoids that occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".class1").hide();
$(".item").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".class1").show();
});
```

```html
 <!--The parent divs should not be empty, otherwise when later in the code you call the .hide () method on their respective child divs, there would be nothing left to click on-->
<div class="item text-center">
  item1
    <div class="class1">  
      <p> Something </p> 
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="item text-center">
      item2
    <div class="class1">  
      <p> Something </p> 
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can use the find () method, the find () method returns the descendant elements of the selected element. Like the code above